# Use of variable of another function in javascript ui datepicker

Tags: javascript

I am calculating date as per selection and then I am storing this calculated date on `exp_dt`variable. This date calculation is under `change` function. What I am trying to achieve is I am calling `exp_dt` in `UI Datepicker` function as `maxDate` but I am getting an error that `exp_dt is not defined`. Is there any way I can use `exp_dt` in `UI Datepicker` function?

My codes so far:

```
$('#date').change(function() {
    var dep_dt = $(this).val();
    $('#eff').val(dep_dt);
    var eff_dt = new Date(dep_dt);
    eff_dt.setDate(eff_dt.getDate() + 364); 
    var month = "0"+(eff_dt.getMonth()+1);
    var date = "0"+eff_dt.getDate();
    month = month.slice(-2);
    date = date.slice(-2);
    var exp_dt = month +"/"+date +"/"+eff_dt.getFullYear();
});

var dateToday = new Date();
$( function() {
$("#date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    minDate: dateToday
    });
$("#eff").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    minDate: dateToday
    });
$("#exp").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    minDate: dateToday
    });
});
```

I am trying to access `exp_dt` in `$("#exp").datepicker({ });` as `maxDate`

```
<input type="text" id="date">
<input type="text" id="eff">
<input type="text" id="exp">
```

Comment: @Mamun And how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add Line 11 to set maxDate value for datepicker;

```
$('#date').change(function() {
        var dep_dt = $(this).val();
        $('#eff').val(dep_dt);
        var eff_dt = new Date(dep_dt);
        eff_dt.setDate(eff_dt.getDate() + 364); 
        var exp_dt = eff_dt;
        $( "#exp" ).datepicker( "option", { maxDate: exp_dt } );
    });

    var dateToday = new Date();
    $( function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        minDate: dateToday
        });
    $("#eff").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        minDate: dateToday
        });
    $("#exp").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: dateToday
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Jason I fixed it; the maxDate get Date type;

Comment: for global varibale in javascript define variable without `var`;use
`exp_dt= ...` 
instead of 
`var exp_dt= ..`

Comment: So here do I need to declare `exp_dt` without var?

Comment: no, because we don't need global variable, we set maxDate in function;
that comment was for information.

Comment: Still it's not working, showing current year 2018 not showing calculated calendar.

Comment: remove line `yearRange: "-100:+0",`
set maxDate after the date element `$("#date")` change and when `$("#date")` change, `$("#eff")` should be filled.

Comment: Did the same thing but not worked, I think `exp_dt` is not working I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a local variable of a function in another function. `exp_dt` is a local variable for the function in change event. Making it a global variable will fix the error.

```
var exp_dt = '';

$('#date').change(function() {
    var dep_dt = $(this).val();
    $('#eff').val(dep_dt);
    var eff_dt = new Date(dep_dt);
    eff_dt.setDate(eff_dt.getDate() + 364); 
    var month = "0"+(eff_dt.getMonth()+1);
    var date = "0"+eff_dt.getDate();
    month = month.slice(-2);
    date = date.slice(-2);
    exp_dt = month +"/"+date +"/"+eff_dt.getFullYear();
});
```

Comment: When I print `exp_dt` using `console.log(exp_dt);` it's not showing any result and code is also not working now by declaring outside